# Testing that a class is @Injectable() in angular2

Tags: angular, tdd

For the TDD purists out there, imagine we are going to write a serivce in Angular2, rc5.

first test is to test that the class definition exists. that is easy.
second test would be to test that the class is decorated with @Injectable (I know it doesn't have to be, but let's say we want to enforce the practice)

so this will fail:

```
export class MyService{}
```

but this will pass:

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";

@Injectable()
export class MyService(){}
```

what would be the test we will write with TestBed to see if the class is Injectable?

My own thoughts were that this is a decorator so maybe I can look at the angular2 source on github and see what it does to a class and test for that, but the source was a bit over my head.

Anyone has done this before?